# Check for child tag inside parent tag

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to know if a parent contains child with specific class name.
Sample code

```
<div id="parent_tag">
   <div id="div1">
      <span>Title 1</span>
   </div>
   <div id="div2">
      <b>Title 2</b>
   </div>
   <div id="div3">
      <span>Title 3</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I trying to access "span tag" only with Title 3. I know I can do it by specifying id. but what if I want to it generically (i.e for all elements). So my first approach should be "I will look for span tag inside div". but I don't know how to do that? Please help.

Comment: Check my answer, but actually I'm not sure that I understand you correctly as you said `child with specific class name`, but in provided `HTML` there are no elements with specified classes...

Answer (score 1):

Try `XPath`:

```
//div/span[text()="Title 3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery selectors to select span in div3:

```
$("#div3 span")
```

Or specifically the first span element inside div3:

```
$("#div3 span:first")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea to get what you need

```
    // Get Parent Element
    WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//div[@id='parent_tag']"));

    // Get All children elements of the parent element
    List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));

    // Init some based param for next usage
    boolean checkClass = false;
    String expectedClass = "Expected_Class";

    // Fetch each child element and check whether its text contains expected string.
    for (WebElement child : children) {       
        if (child.getAttribute("class").contains(expectedClass)) {
            checkClass = true;
        }
    }

    if (checkClass) {
        System.out
                .println("We have at least one child has expected class: "
                        + expectedClass);
    }
    else System.out.println("We don't have any child has expected class: "
                        + expectedClass);
```

if you want to check the text, we could do

```
    if (child.getText().contains(expectedText)) {        
            checkResult = true;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.